# Bad practice to declare your DBContext outside of functions in your controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a controller like below:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Items.ToList());
    }
...
```

Typically when I need to make EF calls I will instantiate the `DBContext` in the function I am using it in and wrap it in a `using` statement like so:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using(MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())
        {
            return View(db.Items.ToList());
        }
    }
```

I found the [first example on the www.asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) which seems like a reputable source(right?), but I'm concerned about the context not being manually disposed of after each use.

Is having a context that is defined outside of the function scope without a `using` statement a bad practice?

Comment: Not really bad practise, as long as you override the controller dispose and dispose the context

Comment: I think it's bad practice for the controller to have any knowledge of dbContext.  It makes testing difficult and it moves your controllers in the direction of fat controllers with logic, whereas controllers ought to be thin and do little, and delegate most work to other classes.

Comment: If you want to test the controller, then you would struggle to do so with this setup.  asp.net is more of a beginners style tutorial, it won't really show you too much in terms of structure etc.

Comment: make sure to dispose the context. also, the longer a context stays around, the slower it gets as updates occur.

Comment: To make it unit testable and thin, implement MediatR

Answer (score 0):

Not if you have something like this:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    db.Dispose();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Since `Controller` is Disposable, it's ok
But generally I try to have a better separation between my controllers and my model.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is the "recommended" way because the context will be disposed when the controller is disposed. Since the controller survives the life of the request, you're ensured that your context will hang around the entire time as well. Using `using` with contexts is dangerous as the context is disposed at a different point in the request and could result in problems if it's accessed after it's been disposed. You're probably okay here since the return is inside the `using` block, but assuming you did something like the following, instead:

```
List<Item> items;
using(MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())
{
    items = db.Items.ToList();
}

return View(items);
```

You'd be in a world of hurt the first time you accessed a navigation property that happened to be lazy-loaded. While, you didn't make that mistake in your code, it's far to easy to make it in general. If you avoid `using` altogether with your contexts, then you're always good.

That said, the *best* way is to actually use dependency injection. For all intents and purposes your context should be treated as a singleton - you don't want multiple instances floating around as that's a recipe for disaster. Using a DI container is a good way to ensure that you achieve that no matter where and in how many different way your context is used. Which DI container to use is a highly personal choice. I prefer Ninject, but there's quite a few other choices that may work better for your personal style. Regardless of which you go with, there should be some sort of option for using "request scope". That is what you'll want to use with your context as it ensures that there's only one instance per request, but every request gets its own instance.